How to get distinct count of max week?
I have 2 columns at the moment and I need to count distinct countries of the last week of my date column. I managed to get the formulas individually but not able to merge them.
Column Date = week(max(Date))
Column Countries = count_distinct(Countries)
Example of my current pivot. I'm trying to track the usage of the website in the last week and want to show it as KPI.



Countries
23-sept
16-sept
9-sept
2-sept




NL
1
1
1
0


DE
0
1
1
1


ES
1
0
1
1


PT
0
0
1
0


FR
1
0
1
1



Thanks in advance!
